# How to alter image size in android?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

[enter image description here][1]I am trying to make a card game using android studio. I have downloaded images of cards and I want the size of the card to be relative to the screen size of the device. I've tried using `layout_weight`, but it still didn't work.
Here is the image:
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/snMNs.png

Here is the code:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/APhZO.png
(Sorry, I couldn't figure out the way to make the image code on stackoverflow cause even after putting 4 spaces after each line, it would still give me errors. Any advice on this would be helpful as well)

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
1. Remove the two LinearLayouts from RelativeLayout. Then add the imageView as a child of RelativeLayout. Then, set the attributes *android:layout_width="wrap_content"* *android:layout_height="wrap_content"* of the ImageView. Your image then will be relative to the screen size.

Suggestion: Read [Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout) about [Layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout) and everything. 
I hope it helps. Let me know if you don't understand anything of my answer.

**Code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/american_style_pool_table_diagram"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_weight="5">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="401dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:contentDescription="image"
        android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/acecardpngcardsacespades600" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The preview of the given code:**

[image: Layout Preview]

2. When you want to add some code, just copy the code and paste below your details and then select only the code portion and then press the '**Code Sample**' button (Button no 5 from left to right) from above. See these:

**Select the Code:**
[image: Select the Code]

**And then press this button:**
[image: Code Sample Button]